# Filtrar por fechas en datagridview c# con datetimerpicker y Mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

Bueno trato de hacer que en un datagridview al seleccionar una fecha desde-hasta me muestre los registros que hay entre esas fechas estoy usando between para hacer esto y la verdad pues no he podido tengo esto en un formulario con un datagrid ,2 datepickers y un boton de buscar

```html
string cadena = ""SELECT ven_consecutivo, p.veh_placa, v.ven_fecha,c.cli_nombre,s.ser_nombre,s.ser_valor FROM serviteca_ventas AS v INNER JOIN  serviteca_vehiculos AS p ON v.`veh_placa` = p.`veh_placa` INNER JOIN serviteca_clientes AS c ON v.`cli_identificacion` = c.`cli_identificacion` INNER JOIN serviteca_servicios AS s ON v.`ser_codigo` = s.`ser_codigo` WHERE v.ven_fecha BETWEEN '"+ DESDE(NOMBRE DEL DATEPICKER.Text"'+hasta(nombre del DatePicker)+"'";
MysqlDataAdapter Adx  = new MysqlDataAdapter(cadena,conexion);

DataSet DS= new DataSet();
Adx.fill(DS);
dtMostrarVentas.DataSource =DS.Tables[0];
```

el problema esta justo en esta linea

MysqlDataAdapter Adx = new MysqlDataAdapter(cadena,conexion);

me dice que conexion no se ha encontrado pues la verdad no supe como hacerlo aclaro yo tengo la clase de conexion por separado no dentro de esto supongo que esta consulta deberia ir en esa clase como tengo las otras el detalle es que si la pongo dentro de la clase me dice que no se encuentra los valores que le puse a los datepicker
esta es mi clase conexion

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace ServiTeca
{
    class Conexion
    {
        private MySqlConnection conexion = new MySqlConnection();
        private string cadena = "server=localhost;user=root;database=serviteca;password=;SslMode=none";
        MySqlCommand consulta = new MySqlCommand();

        public bool Abrir()
        {
            try
            {
                conexion.ConnectionString = cadena;
                conexion.Open();

            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;

        }
        public void Cerrar()
        {
            conexion.Close();
        }
        public int RegistrarServicios(Servicios servicios)
        {
            consulta.CommandText = "INSERT INTO serviteca_servicios VALUES (@ser_codigo,@ser_nombre,@ser_valor)";
            consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ser_codigo", servicios.Codigo);
            consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ser_nombre", servicios.Nombre);
            consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ser_valor", servicios.Valor);
            consulta.Connection = conexion;
            return consulta.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        public DataTable ObtenerServicios()
        {
            consulta.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM serviteca_servicios";
            consulta.Connection = conexion;
            MySqlDataReader dr = consulta.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(dr);
            return dt;

        }
        public int ActualizarServicios(Servicios servicios)
        {
            consulta.CommandText = "UPDATE serviteca_servicios SET ser_nombre=@ser_nombre, ser_valor=@ser_valor WHERE ser_codigo=@ser_codigo";
            consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ser_codigo", servicios.Codigo);
            consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ser_nombre", servicios.Nombre);
            consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ser_valor", servicios.Valor);
            consulta.Connection = conexion;
            return consulta.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        public int CrearCliente(Clientes clientes)
        {
            consulta.CommandText = "INSERT INTO serviteca_clientes VALUES (@cli_identificacion ,@cli_nombre, @cli_telefono, @cli_correo)";
            consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cli_identificacion", clientes.Identificacion);
            consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cli_nombre", clientes.Nombre);
            consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cli_telefono", clientes.Telefono);
            consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cli_correo", clientes.Correo);
            consulta.Connection = conexion;
            return consulta.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        public DataTable ObtenerClientes()
        {
            consulta.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM serviteca_clientes";
            consulta.Connection = conexion;
            MySqlDataReader dr = consulta.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(dr);
            return dt;

        }

        public int ActualizarClientes(Clientes clientes)
        {
            consulta.CommandText = "UPDATE serviteca_clientes SET cli_nombre=@cli_nombre, cli_telefono=@cli_telefono,cli_correo=@cli_correo WHERE cli_identificacion=cli_identificacion";
            consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cli_identificacion", clientes.Identificacion);
            consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cli_nombre", clientes.Nombre);
            consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cli_telefono", clientes.Telefono);
            consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cli_correo", clientes.Correo);
            consulta.Connection = conexion;
            return consulta.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        public int RegistrarAutos(Autos autos)
        {
            consulta.CommandText = "INSERT INTO serviteca_vehiculos VALUES (@veh_placa,@veh_marca,@veh_modelo)";
            consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@veh_placa", autos.Placa);
            consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@veh_marca", autos.Marca);
            consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@veh_modelo", autos.Modelo);
            consulta.Connection = conexion;
            return consulta.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }

        public DataTable ObtenerAutos()
        {
            consulta.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM serviteca_vehiculos";
            consulta.Connection = conexion;
            MySqlDataReader dr = consulta.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(dr);
            return dt;
        }

        public int ActualizarAutos(Autos autos)
        {
            consulta.CommandText = "UPDATE serviteca_vehiculos SET veh_marca=@veh_marca, veh_modelo=@veh_modelo WHERE veh_placa=@veh_placa";
            consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@veh_placa", autos.Placa);
            consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@veh_marca", autos.Marca);
            consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@veh_modelo", autos.Modelo);
            consulta.Connection = conexion;
            return consulta.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        public int RegistrarVentas(Ventas ventas)
        {
            consulta.CommandText = "INSERT INTO serviteca_ventas VALUES (NULL,@ser_codigo,@cli_identificacion,@veh_placa,@ven_fecha,@ven_valor)";
            consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ser_codigo", ventas.Codigo);
            consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cli_identificacion", ventas.Identificacion);
            consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@veh_placa", ventas.Placa);
            consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ven_fecha", ventas.Fecha);
            consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ven_valor", ventas.Valor);
            consulta.Connection = conexion;
            return consulta.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Espero de su colaboracion y gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si estas usando una clase de conexion debes seguir el mismo camino, pero debes pasar los valores del DateTimepicker por parametro

```
public DataTable ObtenerPorRangoFechas(DateTime desde, DateTime hasta)
{
    string cadena = @"SELECT ven_consecutivo, p.veh_placa, v.ven_fecha,c.cli_nombre,s.ser_nombre,s.ser_valor 
                        FROM serviteca_ventas AS v 
                            INNER JOIN  serviteca_vehiculos AS p ON v.`veh_placa` = p.`veh_placa` 
                            INNER JOIN serviteca_clientes AS c ON v.`cli_identificacion` = c.`cli_identificacion` 
                            INNER JOIN serviteca_servicios AS s ON v.`ser_codigo` = s.`ser_codigo` 
                        WHERE v.ven_fecha BETWEEN @desde AND @hasta";

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cadena, conexion);
    consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desde", desde);
    consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hasta", hasta);

    MysqlDataAdapter Adx = new MysqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    Adx.Fill(dt);

    return dt;
}
```

y para invocarlo usarias

```
Conexion conn = new Conexion();
DataTable dt = conn.ObtenerPorRangoFechas(DATEPICKER1.Value, DATEPICKER2.Value);

dtMostrarVentas.DataSource = dt;
```

le pasas el Value del DataTimePicker pr parametro

Comment: Hola amigo no me funciono no me reconoce los nombres del datepicker que tengo en el formulario y al invocarlo me dice que obtenerPorFechas no esta definido

Comment: de donde sale ese cnn. y gracias

Comment: ya edite el ejemplo olvide poner la o

Comment: Me manda error te dejo el link donde lo puse porque no puedo escribir mucho aca no me da te l odejo en una nota en linea https://anotepad.com/notes/nbhgc3

Comment: si falla en el fill es porque no le asignas la instancia del datatable, o sea Adx.Fill(dt);

Comment: Ya mire y esta tal y como dices mira la nota y verad

Comment: ya vi donde esta el problema, porque usas esto: BETWEEN '"+TimeDesde +"'AND '"+ TimeHasta +"'" no se concatema nada en el string, tienes que usar parametros

Comment: tiene que ser: BETWEEN @TimeDesde AND @TimeHasta"

Comment: me vuleve a mandar a adx.Fill();

Comment: que significa que "vuelve a mandar" ? que dice el mensaje del error

Comment: Muestra lo siguiente The SelectCommand property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill'.

Comment: ya veo, el problema es que usas una instancia global del command cuando haces consulta.CommandText = "SELECT...  revisa como defini el ejemplo instanciando MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cadena, conexion); y luego MysqlDataAdapter Adx = new MysqlDataAdapter(cmd); deberias hacerlo de la misma forma, debes tratar que las variables sean lo mas local posible

Comment: Hola amigo ya muestra otro error de lo dejo aca https://anotepad.com/notes/txbb8y y gracias por toda tu ayuda

Comment: si lees el exception veras que menciona "Parameter '@Desde' must be defined." valida que definas ese parametro usando la linea consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desde", desde);

Comment: Pues asi estaba pero ya lo puse asi y nada

Comment: validaste si el parametro lo defines exactamente igual, o sea si es "@desde" o "@Desde" porque quizas esta diferenciando mayusculas y minusculas

Comment: esta igual tanto en la consulta como en los parametros dice lo siguiente public DataTable (DateTime Desde,DateTime Hasta)                                   la consula "select la consulta WHERE v.venfecha BETWEEN @Desde AND @Hasta";                                                                            consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Desde", Desde);
    consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hasta", Hasta);

Comment: pero defines bien los objetos? no estas creando ningun MySqlCommand global cosa que asignes los parametros en una variable diferente al que terminas ejecutando, revisa en mi ejemplo que lo defino local a la funcion